# Al usar la librería de Look and Feel Synthetica me sale un espaciado, ¿es esto un error? ¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, look-and-feel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que al importar una librería de Look and Feel (*Synthetica*) me sale como un espaciado abajo. Ya probé desactivando el `setResizable` pero no me solucionó el problema, luego pensé que era la imagen y tampoco lo es. Parece como si fuera un scroll a mi parecer. ¿Hay alguna manera de que desaparezca?

Esta es la librería Look And Feel que utilizo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaClassyLookAndFeel");
        MantenimientoEmpleado dialog = new MantenimientoEmpleado();
        
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Por lo que veo es problema de la creación de tu JTable en swing y no del look and feel que le pusiste, simplemente le baja el tamaño de la fuente y ya no queda del tamaño que le pusiste en el editor, la primera solución que se me ocurre es darle un menor alto y meterlo en un ScrollPane para que se pueda navegar mediante barras si excede el tamaño del área que le pongas.

Answer (score -1):

Podrías probar con esto
en el constructor de tu formulario

```
  this.setExtendedState(  MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: ese metodo es de un jframe, el de aqui es un jdialog no tiene esa propiedad :( , gracias de todas maneras